# Seg fault in display function for singly linked list

Tags: c++, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement my display function (in my main.cc file). However, when I use my **curr** pointer get data on my **Student** object and then traverse the list, the program core dumps.

MAIN.CC

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

void append (Node **, Node *); //append Node to end of list.
void display(Node *); //print linked list.
void input(Student *); //enter new Student object.
void deleteNode(Node **, string); //delete specific Node.

string first;
string mid;
string last;
string ssn;
string age;

int main() {

    string flag; //flag checks for delimiter.
    string name;
    string stuDelete; //name to be deleted.

    Student * stuPtr = NULL;
    Node * head = NULL;
    Node * newPtr = NULL;

    do {
        stuPtr = new Student;
        input(stuPtr);
        flag = stuPtr ->getFirst(); //flag = first name

        if(stuPtr -> getFirst() == "-") { //"-" is delimiter
            cout << "in if statement\n";
            delete stuPtr; //no new Student, no more need for
                           //temporary Student pointer.
            stuPtr = NULL;
            cout << "checkpoint1" << endl;
        }
        else {
            newPtr = new Node(stuPtr);
            append(& head, newPtr);
            cout << "checkpoint 2" << endl;
        }
    } while (first != "-"); //will prompt for more entries unless
                           //delimiter is detected.

    cout << "checkpoint 3" << endl;
    display(head); // MY DISPLAY FUNCTION SUCKS

    if(head)
        cout << "Enter a Student to be deleted" << endl;
    while(head) {
        cout << "Last name: ";
        cin >> stuDelete;
        deleteNode(& head, stuDelete);

        string reqDelete; // asks if you want to keep deleting.
        cout << "Student has been deleted. Delete another? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> reqDelete;

        if(head != NULL && reqDelete == "Y") {
            display(head); //iterates thru linked list
            cout << "\nEnter another name to be deleted: \n" << endl;
        }
        else if(reqDelete != "Y")
            cout << "Deletion complete.\n" << endl;
    }

    if(head)
        display(head);
    else
    cout << "The list is now empty.\n"
         << "=============================" << endl;

         return 0;

}

    void display (Node * newPtr) {

    Node * curr = newPtr; 

    while(curr != NULL) {
    // getData is used to point to the stud info in a node
    cout << "{" 
         << curr->getData()->getFirst() << ", "
         << curr->getData()->getMiddle() << ", "
         << curr->getData()->getLast()<< ", "
         << curr->getData()->getSocial()<< ", "
         << curr->getData()->getAge()
         << "}" << endl;    
    curr = curr->getNext(); // move to the next obj, traverse stud data
    }
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
}
```

I'll list my headers for my Node and Student class. Let me know if that is not enough info.

NODE.H

```
class Node {

public:
    Node(); //Default constructor.
    Node(Student *); //New constructor.

    Student * getData(); //get data on Student object.
    void setData(Student *); //set data for Student object.

    Node * getNext();   //get the next Node in the linked list.
    void setNext(Node * );  //set the next Node in the list.

private:
    Student * data; //pointer to current Student data.
    Node * next; //pointer within Node to the next Node.

};

#endif
```

STUDENT.H

```
class Student {

public:
    Student(); //Default constructor;
    Student(const string &, const string &, const string &, 
        const string &, const string &); //New constructor.

    //setters
    void setName(const string &, const string &, const string &);
    void setSocial(const string &);
    void setAge(const string &);

    //getters
    string getFirst();
    string getMiddle();
    string getLast();
    string getSocial();
    string getAge();

private:
    string stuData[5]; //array of fields for Student data.
};
```

TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
faruki@ubuntu:~/DataStructures/Lab4$ ./a.out

Enter Student information (Enter '-' to exit)
First Name: jesus
Middle Name: h
Last Name: christ
Social: 222222222
Age: 222
==============================
checkpoint 2

Enter Student information (Enter '-' to exit)
First Name: -
Student entry finished.

==============================
in if statement
checkpoint1
checkpoint 3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

CONSTRUCTORS FOR STUDENT CLASS

```
Student::Student() {
    stuData[0] = "Firstname";
    stuData[1] = "Middlename";
    stuData[2] = "Lastname";
    stuData[3] = "SSN";
    stuData[4] = "##";
}

Student::Student(const string & first, const string & mid, 
    const string & last, const string & ssn, const string & age) {

    setName(first, mid, last);
    setSocial(ssn);
    setAge(age);
}
```

CONSTRUCTORS FOR NODE CLASS

```
Node::Node() {
    next = NULL; //new Nodes go to the end of the list.
}

Node::Node(Student * tempData) {
    data = tempData;
    delete tempData;
    next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please post constructor for Node. Maybe the case that you didn't init Next to null;

Comment: At while (first != "-"); I believe first is not initialized.

Comment: @madnut Added the constructors for both classes.

Comment: @PunDefeated string first is retrieved by the GetFirst() getter function. Sorry for the lack of comments.

Comment: Why not use std::list?

Comment: This lab is to create a singly linked list from scratch. So I am not sure precisely how to use std::list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the node constructor you are deleting the data for the Student, so your Node::data points to invalid memory, so it is most likely not the display function that sucks, but the deleting of the data in the node constructor.
2. Please consider
   2.1 Formatting: No space between '.' or '->' (dereferencing operators) because this makes code very difficult to read
   2.2 Using C++11 constructs like `nullptr` instead of `NULL` 
   2.3 place brackets around ALL if/for/while/... as in maintenance of the code people might add stuff and wonder while it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Removing the "delete tempData" lines from both constructors fixed the seg fault. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll make the formatting corrections. Not sure how to use nullptr exactly. I will look into that.

Comment: `nullptr` will only be available to you, if you can use a C++11 compiler. It is a keyword introduced with the new standard.